# how to display data in mysql like pivot in excel

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot

I have query like this:

```
SELECT DATE,REGION,COUNT(*)
FROM ALL_ID_DATA
WHERE DATE in (SUBDATE(CURDATE(),1),SUBDATE(CURDATE(),2),SUBDATE(CURDATE(),8))
AND DIRECTION='inbound'
AND REASON_1 = 'complaint'
GROUP BY REGION,DATE DESC
```

and the result is
[image: capture]
What is the right query to display like this capture below

[image: result]
Could somebody help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This type of query is known as a `PIVOT`. Unfortunately, MySQL doesn't have a `PIVOT` function, so you will need to replicate the function using a `CASE` statement and an aggregate function.

If you know the number of columns to transform, then you can hard-code the values:

```
select region,
  SUM(CASE WHEN date = '2012-09-24' THEN 1 END) as `2012-09-24`,
  SUM(CASE WHEN date = '2012-09-30' THEN 1 END) as `2012-09-30`,
  SUM(CASE WHEN date = '2012-10-01' THEN 1 END) as `2012-10-01`
from ALL_ID_DATA
group by region;

select region,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN date = '2012-09-24' THEN 1 ELSE null END) as `2012-09-24`,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN date = '2012-09-30' THEN 1 ELSE null END) as `2012-09-30`,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN date = '2012-10-01' THEN 1 ELSE null END) as `2012-10-01`
from ALL_ID_DATA
group by region;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8d705/2).

Then adding this to your existing query, it would be:

```
SELECT REGION,
  SUM(CASE WHEN date = '2012-09-24' THEN 1 END) as `2012-09-24`,
  SUM(CASE WHEN date = '2012-09-30' THEN 1 END) as `2012-09-30`,
  SUM(CASE WHEN date = '2012-10-01' THEN 1 END) as `2012-10-01`
FROM ALL_ID_DATA
WHERE DATE in (SUBDATE(CURDATE(),1),SUBDATE(CURDATE(),2),SUBDATE(CURDATE(),8))
  AND DIRECTION='inbound'
  AND REASON_1 = 'complaint'
GROUP BY REGION
```

OR

```
SELECT REGION,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN date = '2012-09-24' THEN 1 ELSE null END) as `2012-09-24`,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN date = '2012-09-30' THEN 1 ELSE null END) as `2012-09-30`,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN date = '2012-10-01' THEN 1 ELSE null END) as `2012-10-01`
FROM ALL_ID_DATA
WHERE DATE in (SUBDATE(CURDATE(),1),SUBDATE(CURDATE(),2),SUBDATE(CURDATE(),8))
  AND DIRECTION='inbound'
  AND REASON_1 = 'complaint'
GROUP BY REGION
```

Now if you have an unknown number of dates to transform into columns, then you can use [prepared statements](http://buysql.com/mysql/14-how-to-automate-pivot-tables.html) and your query would be similar to this (See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8d705/9)):

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'sum(case when date = ''',
      date,
      ''' then 1 else 0 end) AS ''',
      Date(date), ''''
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM ALL_ID_DATA;

select @sql;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT region, ', @sql, ' 
                   FROM ALL_ID_DATA
                   GROUP BY region');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Then placing your original query in the prepared statement the final query would be:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'sum(case when date = ''',
      date,
      ''' then 1 else 0 end) AS ''',
      Date(date), ''''
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM ALL_ID_DATA;

select @sql;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT region, ', @sql, ' 
                   FROM ALL_ID_DATA
                   WHERE DATE in (SUBDATE(CURDATE(),1),SUBDATE(CURDATE(),2),SUBDATE(CURDATE(),8))
                   AND DIRECTION=''inbound''
                   AND REASON_1 = ''complaint''');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for this : 
http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php#78